# Multilayer Perceptron Classifier attributes

Tags: deep-learning

> I am training a neural network using Multilayer Perceptron classifier from scikit-learn on MNIST dataset for specifically classifying digits 0,1 and 7 in the dataset.

> Here's the code snippet:

```
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
    mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=4, max_iter=1000, verbose = True, 
                        random_state=211)
```

> Here how do we decide what value to assign for hidden_layer_sizes and max_iter?
>
> I am trying to plet loss function to see how my model is learning. Please see below:

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   plt.plot(mlp.loss_curve_)
   plt.xlabel('Number of epochs')
   plt.ylabel('loss')
   plt.title('The loss curve for our mlp classifier')
   None
```

[image]

> Looking at the above plot, what should i deduce and understand and how my model is learning?

Then i am deriving a classification report  for learning performance measures:

```
  from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
  report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
  print(report)
```

> > ```
> >           precision    recall  f1-score   support
> > ```
>
> ```
>        0       1.00      1.00      1.00        59
>        1       1.00      1.00      1.00        60
>        7       1.00      1.00      1.00        59
>
> accuracy                           1.00       178    macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       178 weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       178
> ```
>
> what need to be understood from above classification report and how the digits 0,1 and 7  are getting classified in above report?

Thanks!!